# Large file transfer over AWS IoT Core

Tags: aws-iot-core

Since the block data size to publish on AWS IoT Core is 128 KB, and according to AWS documentation, it can be increased up to 24 MB, but I don't know how to implement it on both the publishing and subscribing sides. Has anyone had experience with this?

I did this for one data block, but I am not sure how the implementation would be for more than one block on both the publisher and subscriber sides, especially on the subscriber side.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the block data size up to 24 MB on AWS IoT Core, you would need to implement chunking of your data on the publisher side and assemble the chunks on the subscriber side.

***On the Publisher side:***

- Break down your data into chunks where each chunk is less than or
  equal to 128KB (the maximum size of a message in AWS IoT Core).
- Publish these chunks to AWS IoT Core one by one.

pseudo-code:

```py
data = "your data here"
chunk_size = 128 * 1024  # 128 KB
chunks = [data[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(data), chunk_size)]

for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
    publish_to_iot_core(chunk)
```

***On the Subscriber side:***

- Subscribe to the topic on which the data chunks are being published.
- As you receive each chunk, append it to the previously received
  chunks.
- Once all chunks have been received, you can then process the complete
  data.

pseudo-code:

```py
data = ""

def on_message_received(chunk):
    global data
    data += chunk
    process_data(data)

subscribe_to_topic(on_message_received)
```

Remember to handle the policies for publishing, subscribing, and receiving messages as per the AWS IoT Core documentation.

Also note that this approach assumes that the chunks will arrive in the correct order and all chunks will arrive. If these assumptions can't be guaranteed, you might need to include identifiers in your chunks and implement logic to reorder and/or request missing chunks.